# Create random numbers for sums

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create random numbers but the numbers arent random in the labels 2 are random but all the sums are the same:

Here is my code

```
int input = int.Parse(txt1.Text);
    if (input <= 6)
    {
        int Getal1 = 0;
        int Getal2 = 0;
        Random generator = new Random();
        for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
        {
            Getal1 = generator.Next(input) + 1;
            Getal2 = generator.Next(input) + 1;
            Getal1.ToString();
            Getal2.ToString();
        }
        //int Getal2 = generator.Next(input) + 1;
        //int Getal3 = generator.Next(input) + 1;
        //int Getal4 = generator.Next(input) + 1;
        //int Getal5 = generator.Next(input) + 1;
        //int Getal6 = generator.Next(input) + 1;
        //int Getal7 = generator.Next(input) + 1;
        //int Getal8 = generator.Next(input) + 1;
        //int Getal9 = generator.Next(input) + 1;
        //int Getal10 = generator.Next(input) + 1;


        lbl1.Text = Getal1.ToString();
        lbl2.Text = Getal2.ToString();
        lbl3.Text = Getal1.ToString();
        lbl4.Text = Getal2.ToString();
        lbl5.Text = Getal1.ToString();
        lbl6.Text = Getal2.ToString();
        lbl7.Text = Getal1.ToString();
        lbl8.Text = Getal2.ToString();
        lbl9.Text = Getal1.ToString();
        lbl10.Text = Getal2.ToString();
```

It does work when i remove the loop and undo the commentary. But that is so much code i think i can do it smaller.

Comment: 1)You should declare  variable "int Getal1" outside of for loop body because now this variable is visible only in the for loop
2)Why you are using for loop if it not give you any other effect except declaring again and again Getal1 and Getal2 values ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move `Random generator = new Random();` and all the variable declarations outside the loop. You can also put all the labels into an array, so you don't have to assign each separately. Also you've assigned the label's text only to the latest `Getal1, Getal2` values. That's why only all other pairs got the same value as the first one.

```
int input = int.Parse(txt1.Text);
if (input <= 6)
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    Label[] labels = new [] {
        lbl1,
        lbl2,
        lbl3,
        lbl4,
        lbl5,
        lbl6,
        lbl7,
        lbl8,
        lbl9,
        lbl10
    };

    for (int x = 0; x < labels.Length; x++)
    {
        labels[x].Text = (generator.Next(1, input)).ToString();
    }

    error.Text = "";
    pnl1.Visible = true;
}
```

The default `Random` constructor initializes the random seed to a value based on the current time.

Comment: but then the Getal1.ToString() and Getal2.ToString() doesn't work.It says it doesnt excist

Comment: @KipVerslaafde You should also move the variable declarations outside the loop. I've updated the answer.

Comment: A local or parameter named 'Getal2' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter getting this error code now

Comment: `generator.Next(1, input);` - random from `1` up and including `input` is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int input = int.Parse(txt1.Text);   
     Random r = new Random();
                    List<int> sums = new List<int>();
                    if(input<=8)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                        {
                            sums.Add( r.Next(input)+ r.Next(input));
                        }
 lbl1.Text = sums[0].ToString();
                    }
```